# UITableView Delegate callings differently on device and simulator?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, delegates, ios-simulator

We are facing an issue while running app on iPad (iOS version 11.2), it calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` first instead of calling `heightForRowAtIndexPath` at first time. 
And if we run it on simulator then its running perfectly all right, `heightForRowAtIndexPath` calls at first time and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after that. Can anyone tell us what is this problem?

Comment: Perhaps including your relevant code might help.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you rely on the order of invocations of delegate methods?
There is no information about order of calling delegate's methods, in 
the official documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview?language=objc), and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)).
You should't rely on concrete behaviour, this behaviour can be changed in the future.
I think you can remake architecture of your application to avoid this problem.